# TypeScript function parameter allow multiple elements from enum

Tags: typescript

I have an enum.

```
export enum Operation {
    ALL = 'all',
    CREATE = 'create',
    UPDATE = 'update',
    DELETE = 'delete',
}
```

I would like to create a function where you can pass array, but you can't use all Operation just two from them. (Update: two specified)

```
callMe(operations: [Operation.UPDATE|Operation.DELETE]) => {...}
or
callMe(operations: [Operation.UPDATE,Operation.DELETE]) => {...}

let res = callMe([Operation.UPDATE]) // WORKS
let res = callMe([Operation.UPDATE, Operation.DELETE]) // Would like to work
```

Got different error based on ',' or '|'

```
  Source has 2 element(s) but target allows only 1.

  Source has 1 element(s) but target requires 2.
```

Is it possible with TypeScript?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`operations` is not an array but a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of one or two elements:

```
// Tuple with exactly one element (union)
callMe(operations: [Operation.UPDATE | Operation.DELETE]) => {...}

// Tuple with exactly two elements
callMe(operations: [Operation.UPDATE, Operation.DELETE]) => {...}
```

An array would look like:

```
callMe(operations: Operation[]) => {...}
```

Maybe a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set?retiredLocale=de) is a better solution since it only contains unique values (though I do not like the `All` member of your enum - but that is up to you):

```
callMe(operations: Set<Operation>) => {...}
```

**EDIT:** In the end there are many possibilities to get it done. Maybe even something like this:

```
const callMe = (oerations: Operation.ALL | Record<Exclude<Operation, Operation.ALL | Operation.CREATE>, boolean>): void => {}

callMe(Operation.ALL);
callMe({ [Operation.DELETE]: true, update: false });
callMe({ delete: true, update: true });
```

Comment: Thank you. Good to know it's a tuple. 
Set is good cause of unique values. Thanks for it. I want to allow pass only 'Update' and 'Delete' but not allow to pass 'Create'

Comment: Thank you for solution. Exclude solution is not the best cause if you add a new enum then you should go back and extend the function parameter. Still looking for another solution. Sorry :)

Comment: Extract<> works instead of Exclude<>

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid use `Record<Extract<Operation, Operation.UPDATE | Operation.DELETE>>`

Then possible to use: `Array<Extract<Operation, Operation.UPDATE | Operation.DELETE>>`

But it will allow pass same multiple time.